# Responsive menu not closing on item selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

EDIT: I'm not trying to be pushy but if someone knows how to help me with this, I'd really appreciate it.

[www.kwpei.com](http://kwpei.com) is the site I'm working on, the issue I'm having is with the responsive menu not closing after a menu or submenu item is chosen. Ive been told the place to make the change needed is in global.js which I've included here in its current state. Could someone show me how to fix the issue?

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

$('.site-header').addClass('front-page-header');

$('.footer-widgets').prop('id', 'footer-widgets');

$(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');

$(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu").slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 800) {
        $(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu, nav .sub-menu").removeAttr("style");
        $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");
    }
});

$(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
    if (event.target !== this)
    return;
        $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
    });
});

// Local Scroll Speed
$.localScroll({
    duration: 750
});

// Sticky Navigation
var headerHeight = $('.site-header').innerHeight();
var beforeheaderHeight = $('.before-header').outerHeight();
var abovenavHeight = headerHeight + beforeheaderHeight - 1;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > abovenavHeight){

        $('.nav-primary').addClass('fixed');

    } else {

        $('.nav-primary').removeClass('fixed');

    }

});
```

});

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing (running Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m, on Windows 10)

Comment: The hamburger menu(responsive menu) after 800px does not close after you select an item from it unless you close it manually by hitting the hamburger again... Id like it to close immediatly after selecting an item. I'm not talking about the desktop menu, just the one that appears on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slide up the menu again on clicking any of the menu items. Try adding this bit of jquery:

```
$('.menu-item a').click(function () {
    $('.responsive-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

EDIT:

```
$('.menu-item a').click(function () {
if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $('.responsive-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $('.menu-item').removeClass('menu-open');
    }
});
```

If 800px is your breakpoint in the media query

Comment: Trying it right now, even if it doesnt work, I'm saying thank you. One moment and I'll let you know.

Comment: I may not have added that right... it broke my header and my responsive menu

Comment: I copied your two lines directly under $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");

Comment: add it just before the comment: // Local Scroll Speed

Comment: It shortened the code but I added it directly under the other two lines referring to responsive-menu

Comment: And it is actually a nice effect as it closes the menu AND scrolls to the menu item, thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: Just noticed it doesnt close a submenu if the user clicks one... is there a way to modify it to do so?

Comment: You want the sub menu as well as the responsive menu to close on clicking the sub menu item?

Comment: Just add this line: 
$('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(); after 
$('.responsive-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();

Comment: Also wrap everything in an if statement so the menus will only slide up for mobile if ($(window).width() > 640) { } where 640 is the breakpoint (change to whatever you've got).

Comment: what am I doing wrong with this wrap? if ($(window).width() > 640) {
        $('.menu-item a').click(function () {
        $('.responsive-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(); after $('.responsive-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
        
        });

Comment: Take a look now at www.kwpei.com at how it works with that additon from your jfiddle

Comment: Try clicking an item in the full sized menu now... it makes the menu... go away permanently

Comment: Sorry > needs to be < I will update the code in my answer.

Comment: odd.. Im not seeing you jsfiddle look any different... this is what I see there... $('.menu-item a').click(function () {
if ($(window).width() > 640) {
    $('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $('.responsive-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    }
});

Comment: hi, disregard that fiddle. I have added updated code in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125877/discussion-between-redtail-and-wim-mertens).